# user pictures not showing up in posts & comments

Tags: theming, comments, users

I am using a custom theme and it is not showing user pics in comments.

When I compared 'Appearance > Settings > Toggle display settings' of my theme with Bartik, if found that "User pictures in posts" & "User pictures in comments" is missing in my theme settings.

I don't understand what I am missing in my theme. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

comment.tpl.php is the template file which controls the view of comments in a page. You may search for this template file in your theme and edit it according to your requirement.

If you would like to customize the comments display for a specific content type the template file would be comment--node-[type].tpl.php

Comment: Yes Bhuvana, I do have this comment tpl file. It is same as Bartik and other themes. When I use other themes, the user pictures are showing up but when I use it in my own customised theme, the user pictures are missing. Please help.

Comment: I searched for this solution, and found that the option is missing in 'Appearance > Settings > Toggle display.
But Bartik have this option in their theme settings.